# What is the infrastructure used for Stackoverflow, Twitter, LinkedIn and Facebook

Tags: social-networking, infrastructure, web-development-server

I am curious, what is the infrastructure used for the following websites : Stackoverflow, Twitter, LinkedIn and Facebook ? (or any other social networks)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by infrastructure?

Comment: Most of them use computers

Comment: Downvoting because the only answer to such a wide question is: server farms of some sort

Comment: Detailed infrastructure for stack overflow [here](http://highscalability.com/stack-overflow-architecture).

Answer (score 1):

Twitter: Ruby on Rails project ([ref](http://www.forbes.com/forbes/2009/0622/software-internet-innovation-digital-tools.html))

StackOverflow: ASP.NET MVC ([ref](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/))

Comment: I think that Twitter reference is old...